# WordPress Calling Backend Options

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a menu with a option and text field which seems to save the text i have placed into it when clicking save. the post action is to send to the options.php page but im not sure what to create in that file. Im guessing it does not save the inputted data into wordpress like it would do for options in customiser or is that still possible, codex didnt seem to cover it that i could find. Once a option is set i should then be able to call it using,  correct?

Below is my code for the form:

Page Creation and register settings function (this seemed to be the way it was done in the codex)

```
// =========================================================================== //
// ADDING THE ADMIN MENU FOR THEME
// ====================================================================================== //
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'dcmaintheme_menu' );

function dcmaintheme_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'dcmaintheme_adminpage', 'Dragon Cove Theme', 'manage_options', 'dcmaintheme_adminpage', 'dcmaintheme_page', content_url( 'themes/dragoncove/images/icon.png' ), 100 );
    add_submenu_page( 'dcmaintheme_adminpage', 'Reference', 'Reference', 'manage_options', 'submenu_reference_page', 'submenu_reference_page' );


    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_unloadAdminStyle_settings' );
}
```

Form Code Below:

```
// ADMIN PAGE
// ===========================================================================     //

function register_unloadAdminStyle_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'unloadAdminStyle_group', 'dc_adminStyle_option' );
    register_setting( 'unloadAdminStyle_group', 'dc_adminStyle_option_toggle' );
    }


function dcmaintheme_page() {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
?> 
    <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Some Option Menu</h2>;

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields( 'unloadAdminStyle_settings' ); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections( 'unloadAdminStyle_settings' ); ?>
                <table class="form-table">
                    <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Unload Admin Stylesheet</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="adminStyle_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('adminStyle_option') ); ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <?php submit_button(); ?>

            </form> 
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure quite what you're asking, but options.php is a file in the /wp-admin directory that will handle updating the settings, there's no need to create/modify an additional file.